# Error when I delete Blade components classes to make them anonymous

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade

I started my project by creating normal components and now want to convert some to anonymous components.

I know that the absence of the class makes components **anonymous**.

### Sample

I have this view page code:

```html
<x-icons.plus />
```

When I delete `app\View\Components\Icons\Plus.php` and revisit the page I get the following error:

```
ErrorException
include(\path\vendor\composer/../../app/View/Components/Icons/Plus.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

I followed this answer from [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-make-a-blade-component-anonymous) and cleared the cache. But the same error persists.

What is very confusing is when I create a new component using `php .\artisan make:component bruh.plus --view` and use it as `<x-bruh.plus/>` on the same page all works fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are all the needed steps:

1. Clear Laravel view's cache

```
php artisan view:clear
```

2. Regenerates the autoloader files in your project

```
composer dump-autoload
```